# Running Opendaylight from Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, java

In order to build SDN testbed, I have installed VirtualBox to run Mininet and OpenDayLight controller. Hence, to install and run OpenDayLight, I have followed this [tutorial](https://enterpriseadmin.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/how-to-install-opendaylight-sdn-controller-at-virtualbox/). No problem occurred until I tried to actually run the command `./karaf` from within the vm terminal.

It shows me the following message:

```
./karaf: 242: [: Illegal number:  

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UnsyncloadClass was deprecated in 
 version 10.0 and will likely be removed in a future release. 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize;
 support was removed in 8.0

-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/default java/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/lib/jvm/default
 java/lib/endorsed:/home/odlc/distribution-karaf-0.4.0 Beryllium/lib/endorsed
is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular
form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules. 

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you installed Ubuntu 18.04 Server when you followed the tutorial.

If so, I think the problem might be related to the version of Java installed. In 18.04 the package `default-jre-headless` installs OpenJDK 11. I tried with this and received the same error as you.

It looks like it does work with OpenJDK 8 and you should be able to resolve this as follows:

**Remove OpenJDK 11**

```
sudo apt remove default-jre-headless
sudo apt autoremove
```

**Add Universe Software Repository (Required for OpenJDK 8)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

**Install OpenJDK 8**

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

**Amend bashrc**

Open the file `~/.bashrc` and amend the line you added previously to:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Re-run the amended file with `source ~/.bashrc` and then try running karaf again.

Comment: Thank you. You are right all the way: It's a Java compatibility issue with Ubuntu 18.04. What I did is a little different though. I just downgraded my Java version.