# Running opendaylight on ubuntu using vmware workstation 14

Tags: vmware-workstation

In order to build SDN testbed, I have installed Vmware workstation 14 pro to run Mininet and OpenDayLight controller. Hence, to install and run OpenDayLight, I have followed a tutorial. No problem occurred until I tried to run this command `sudo ./distribution-karaf-0.4.0-Beryllium/bin/karaf` from within the vmware terminal.

It shows me the following message:

```
karaf: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary
./distribution-karaf-0.4.0-Beryllium/bin/karaf: 242: [:Illegal number:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option Unsyncloadclass; support was removed in 11.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option Maxpermsize; support was removed in 8.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/endorsed:/home/zeal/distribution-karaf-0.4.0-Beryllium/lib/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

Error: Could not create the java virtual machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occured. program will exit.
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For opendaylight you need openjdk-8 but you have installed the openjdk-11.
This [Running Opendaylight from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059751/running-opendaylight-from-ubuntu) might help you